# Time series question from book (ma)

Tags: econometrics, time-series, theory

I'm trying to understand this subject and  I'm stuck in a question found in a book. [image]

I understand white noise characterization, but I'm having some problems with this... maybe it's too much theory? I kind of get lost when I try to prove that also the new variable $Y$ is MA, and don't get me started on solving for the parameters. Maybe some hints on how to proceed or explain the steps I need to follow?

Edit 1:

I've posted the question on Cross Validated. Also the book you suggested in the comments,  Hamilton, *Time Series Analysis*,  is one of the many I'm using in my class and you were right, the solution is right there, just written in a different way. I guess that at page 102 $X_t$ in the book is my $u_t$ and $v_t$ in the book is my $w_t$, whereas $Y_t$ is the same in both cases. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Hi: just write out the MA(1) term explicitly. This will allow you to combine the $w_t$ term with the pure noise term in the MA(1) to create a new noise term. But overall process is still MA(1). I'm in a rush so, if this isn't clear, hopefully someone has the time to write it out for you. If not, I'll write it out later tonight when I get back.

Comment: Do you have or have access to  Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis" text.  The proof of your statement is on page 102 in the section called sums of ARMA processes.

Comment: This is not about economics but about a statistical time series model, so I think it would be a better fit or [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions).